# Как прикрутить к слайдеру автопрокрутку?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такой скрипт, который листает блоки нажатием на стрелки вперед и назад:

```
 jQuery.fn.slider = function( options ) {
    var options = jQuery.extend({
        startLeft: 0
        },
        options); 
    return this.each(function() {
        var currentSlide = 0;
        var width = options.width;
        var cont = $(this).find("ul");
        var items = cont.find("li");
        var navleft = $(this).find(".nav-left");
        var navright = $(this).find(".nav-right");
        cont.prepend("<li>" + items.eq(items.length - 1).html() + "</li>");
        cont.append("<li>" + items.eq(0).html() + "</li>");
        var itemsExt = cont.find("li");

        cont.css({left: -width - options.startLeft});
        var margin = -width - options.startLeft;
        var animation = false;

        navleft.click(function(){
            if(!animation){
                animation = true;
                margin += width;
                cont.animate(
                {
                    left: margin
                },
                function()
                {
                    animation = false;
                    if(currentSlide == 0)
                    {
                        currentSlide = items.length - 1;
                        margin = -width * items.length - options.startLeft;
                        cont.css({left: margin});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        --currentSlide;
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

        navright.click(function(){
            if(!animation){
                animation = true;
                margin -= width;
                cont.animate(
                {
                    left: margin
                },
                function()
                {
                    animation = false;
                    if(currentSlide == items.length - 1)
                    {
                        currentSlide = 0;
                        margin = -width - options.startLeft;
                        cont.css({left: margin});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ++currentSlide;
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
 };
```

Вызывается так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".rooms-main").slider({
        width: 252
    });
});
```

Как сюда прикрутить функцию, чтобы он автоматически листался через, н-р, 3 секунды?

Вот пример скрипта - http://jsfiddle.net/5b9S9/1/

Comment: копайте в сторону

`setInterval` + `$.('selector').click()`

остальное оставляю вам на обучение

Comment: маленький совет: *не блокируйте анимацией функционал итерфейса* :) 
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/5b9S9/3/

Comment: у вас же есть пременная  *`navright`* зачем вы еще раз ищете этот элемент да ещё и с корня DOM ?

Comment: хорошо, а как это упростить?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/5b9S9/5/

Comment: кое что исправил, добавил паузу на hover

Comment: Спасибо. Кстати, этот код не работает в jQuery 1.8.3, который я использую.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/5b9S9/6/ вот в 1.8.3

Comment: )) Вопрос про событие на hover должен был быть следующим, заранее спасибо))